# Why is my cake not rising

Tags: baking

I have been cooking this cake for years. Recently, it rises, but not as high as it used to. It's about a half inch lower. I use 2 Duncan Hines butter golden cake mixes, 8 eggs, 1 cup of oil and 16 oz sour cream. I bake at 350 degrees for 30-35 minutes. I do put my cake higher in the oven because I don't want the bottom to be dark, could that be the problem?

Comment: Do you have an oven thermometer to verify that your oven is still producing good heat?

Comment: What has changed since you baked it successfully?

Comment: Could it be shrinkflation, i.e. has the quantity in the box been silently reduced?

Answer (score -2):

Check the date on the mix. If its near expiry the raising agents could be losing strength. Or could be that Duncan  Hines have changed their recipe?

Comment: Most ‘use by’ dates go well beyond when the food would actually have an issue.  Getting near the date shouldn’t be an issue unless you’re in an extreme climate area.  If it were years past the date, then you might have issues